# Does dismissing a view controller call destructor of the ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`.

Now `ViewControllerA` launches `ViewControllerB` through an action as such

```
 self.view_library = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil]; //Initialize a view controller/
[self presentViewController:self.view_library animated:YES completion:nil]; //Display the new view controller
```

Now in ViewControllerB i return the control back to ViewControllerA as such

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

My question is will the destructor of `ViewControllerB` be called ? Will I have to `alloc` it again to display it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely not thinking about this correctly. This line creates a strong reference to a new `ViewControllerB` instance:

```
self.view_library = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil]; //Initialize a view controller/
```

(Don't put underscores in your variable names; this is confusing to ObjC and bad for key-value-coding conventions that Cocoa relies on.)

This line *probably* (but it isn't your business) adds an extra retain to the view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:self.view_library animated:YES completion:nil]; //Display the new view controller
```

This line *probably* (but it isn't your business) removes a retain from the view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

So, adding together what is certain with what is likely, that's +1, +1, -1. So you still have one retain on the object, and it will not be deallocated (`dealloc` is not the same as a destructor; that's related to C++ and has different semantics).

If, after dismissing the view controller, you set `self.view_library` to something else, then its retain will be removed from the object, and (if nothing else has retained it) the view controller will be deallocated.

The point is that you need to focus on balancing your retains and releases, which is mostly handled for you by ARC (one is retained when you assign to a strong variable, and one is released when that strong variable stops referring to it).

To your specific question, yes, should likely re-create the view controller. That's the common solution, even if it's not always required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC and `self.view_library` has `strong` reference it will not be deallocated, so you don't need to `alloc` it again.

Comment: So in short it does not call the destructor ? What if its a not a strong reference ?

Comment: It doesn't dealloc the object. If it doesn't have `strong` reference, it should be dealloc and you need to realloc the object in order to `presentViewController` again.